# how to get the data from mysql result in node.js and display it on index.hbs

Tags: node.js

i am connecting to mysql in connect.js and i am retriving the data in index.js using connection object ...and the results are getting stored in result ....i need to render it to index.hbs ....how can i do this ....thanks for helping

i am running on windows

Connect.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connectDB = {};

connectDB.connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  port: '3306'
});

connectDB.connection.connect(function(err) {

    if (err) throw err;

});

module.exports.db = connectDB;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var databasecon = require('../views/partials/connect.js');

function get_info(callback){
const test_connection = databasecon.db.connection.query("SELECT * FROM `cs`.`users`", function (err, result, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
 // console.log(result);
  callback(result);
});
}
get_info(function(result){
  console.log(result);

});


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping-cart' });
});

module.exports = router;

}
```

i need to display the  result of mysql to my index.hbs